# Restrict certain backend wordpress pages by user role

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to restrict certain backend pages in wordpress by user role. I have tried the Adminimize plugin to do this but it only removes the link from the menu item but not restrict the page.

The code I am trying to work with is:

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'exclude_pages_from_admin' );

function exclude_pages_from_admin($query) {
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$role = ( array ) $user->roles;

if ($role == 'subscriber') {
global $pagenow,$post_type;
 if (is_admin() && $pagenow=='settings.php') {
   echo 'You are not allowed to edit this page';
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Read: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91330/restrict-admin-access-to-certain-pages-for-certain-users

Comment: I tried this but cannot seem to get it to work based on user role

Comment: Just try to fetch role from ID. If user is login there should be ID

Comment: @PawanThakur I tried the `add_filter( 'parse_query', 'exclude_pages_from_admin' );

$user_id = get_current_user_id();

if ($user_id == 3) {
    function exclude_pages_from_admin($query) {
        global $pagenow,$post_type;
        if (is_admin() && $pagenow=='profile.php') {
            echo 'not allowed';
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Try this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169170/how-can-i-remove-the-add-new-button-in-my-custom-post-type/233603#233603

Comment: Also try it: https://alka-web.com/blog/how-to-restrict-access-to-wordpress-dashboard-programmatically/